# Same maven with different behaviours

Tags: java, r, postgresql, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to use `Vagrant` to create my `new virtual machine` with `Jenkins` to ensure the quality of my builds/projects. The project needs to use `R` and `Postgres` as well. Everything works fine in my local machine, but now I'm trying to make my environment consistent, reproducible. When I try to run `mvn clean package` in my new virtual machine, `maven` breaks in a `test` which runs normally in my local machine but **not** in my new vm.

I have checked the versions for `Java`, `Maven`, `Postgres`, `R` (and its `packages`) everything is the same. But still, my maven project breaks in this test.

What am I missing here ? Any idea, suggestion is well appreciated because I'm out of ideas right now, I tried everything so far. (more than 12 hours on this issue..)

**EDIT**

Java - Host Machine

```
valter@eniac:document-engine$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

Java - Virtual Machine

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

Maven - Host Machine

```
valter@eniac:document-engine$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_66, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.19.0-31-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Maven - Virtual Machine

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_65/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-66-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$
```

Postgresql - Host Machine

```
valter@eniac:document-engine$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.10
```

Postgresql - Virtual Machine

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.10
```

R - Host Machine

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3541 xts_0.9-7                    
 [3] zoo_1.7-12                    HiddenMarkov_1.8-4           
 [5] gplots_2.17.0                 gmodels_2.16.2               
 [7] gtools_3.5.0                  lattice_0.20-33              
 [9] MASS_7.3-44                   tseries_0.10-34              
[11] fGarch_3010.82                fBasics_3011.87              
[13] timeSeries_3012.99            timeDate_3012.100            
[15] Rserve_1.7-3                 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] quadprog_1.5-5     bitops_1.0-6       grid_3.2.2         KernSmooth_2.23-15
[5] gdata_2.17.0       caTools_1.17.1
```

R - Virtual Machine

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3541 xts_0.9-7                    
 [3] zoo_1.7-12                    HiddenMarkov_1.8-4           
 [5] gplots_2.17.0                 gmodels_2.16.2               
 [7] gtools_3.5.0                  lattice_0.20-33              
 [9] MASS_7.3-44                   tseries_0.10-34              
[11] fGarch_3010.82                fBasics_3011.87              
[13] timeSeries_3012.99            timeDate_3012.100            
[15] Rserve_1.7-3                 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] quadprog_1.5-5     bitops_1.0-6       grid_3.2.2         KernSmooth_2.23-15
[5] gdata_2.17.0       caTools_1.17.1
```

Comment: What kind of test failure is it? There may be cases where tests run on one OS, but not on another.

Comment: We're using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS @hotzst. Is the same OS, the only difference is that the host machine is a desktop version and the other is a server version.

Comment: Is the test threaded in any way? Some Java installations on server machines dynamically add the `-server` flag to the JVM when starting. This flag optimizes JIT compilation (especially code reliant on the JMM, such as threads) more aggressively which could affect your tests.

Comment: Which version of maven do you use ? Have you pinned all maven plugins which are used during the build?  Are you using the maven version which installed by OS or downloaded manually?

Comment: Have you tried purging the local repository on your development machine? This acts like a cache, you make have jars there that do not exist on the Jenkins build server.

Comment: @Daniel How can I check this ? I'm doing `ps -ef | grep java` and watching my `java` calls and this flag `-server` didn't show up.

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm using `maven` 3.0.5. in both. And I ran the command `mvn help:effective-pom` and in both machines shows the build was successful.

Comment: You didn't answer my question: Have you pinned all plugins you are using?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm sorry. Can you please tell how to do that ? Please.

Comment: Unfortunately, `ps -ef | grep java` doesn't always tell you the full truth. Come to think of it, I think a simple `java -version` tells you the default flavor of your JVM. Nevertheless, try a `java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version` and see if there are other flags that differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let you know what happened with my issue.
The problem was the **TIMEZONE**. I don't know exactly why, but `R` or some of the packages that we use for our calculations requires the timezone to be the same.

I'm located in Germany (timezone CET which is [+1 UTC](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cet)) and I was setting my virtual machine to use UTC and thus the problem. Oh man, I'm really glad to solve this issue (3 days straight working on this!) but now everything is fine! A huge thank you to my colleague `@Ralf` for the tip!

Other issue related:[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33393040/why-r-calculations-are-inconsistent-in-my-virtual-machine), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33393040/why-r-calculations-are-inconsistent-in-my-virtual-machine), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384755/same-maven-with-different-behaviours).
I hope this helps someone! :)